# Cannon run command freshclam for clamav

Tags: 16.04, antivirus, clamav

I installed clamav antivirus for Linux. Now I ran the following command in the terminal and got an error. How do I fix it?

```
$ sudo freshclam
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

Answer (score 2):

`freshclam` should be already running as a daemon, that is why you are getting that message.  If you run the following command you should see updates are happening:

```
tail -10 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

Here's an example of mine:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ tail -10 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
Fri Dec 23 19:08:16 2016 -> safebrowsing.cld is up to date (version: 45370, sigs: 2490012, f-level: 63, builder: google)
Fri Dec 23 19:08:16 2016 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 285, sigs: 57, f-level: 63, builder: bbaker)
Fri Dec 23 19:08:16 2016 -> --------------------------------------
Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016 -> Received signal: wake up
Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016 -> ClamAV update process started at Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016
Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016 -> main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016 -> daily.cld is up to date (version: 22765, sigs: 1152120, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016 -> safebrowsing.cld is up to date (version: 45370, sigs: 2490012, f-level: 63, builder: google)
Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016 -> bytecode.cld is up to date (version: 285, sigs: 57, f-level: 63, builder: bbaker)
Fri Dec 23 20:08:16 2016 -> --------------------------------------
```

As you can see, mine updated just a few moments ago.  If you want to change the update intervals, run the following command from a terminal window:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

Then just step through the prompts, and you can change the number of freshclam updates per day (24 means once per hour):

[image]

Hope this helps!